# Why would `mediaCapture.captureImage()` crash my `ionic` app?

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an IOS app in `ionic` that captures media (photo, video, audio) and ran into a quite confounding issue today. I'm using the following 3 methods (on [`MediaCapture`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture/)):

- `captureImage()`
- `captureVideo()`
- `captureAudio()`

The *only* one that doesn't work is `captureImage()` and I can't, for the life of me, figure out why. **Side note**: I *was* able to use `camera.getPicture()` but I'd like to use `MediaCapture` for all 3 media types (and it doesn't make sense why I can't).

Here are some details:

#### Environment

- **OS**: Mac OS 10.12.6
- **Node**: 9.0.0
- **`ionic`**: 3.15.2
- **`Cordova`**: 7.1.0
- **iOS**: 11.1

I'm running the app on my device using `ionic cordova run ios -l -c -s`.

#### Sample code

Example Code (extracted Typescript)

```
private media: object = {
  'image': 'captureImage',
  'video': 'captureVideo',
  'audio': 'captureAudio'
};

function captureMedia(media) {
  console.log('capturing');
  const options: CaptureImageOptions = {
    limit: 1
  };
  this.mediaCapture[this.media[media]](options)
    .then(
      (data: MediaFile[]) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)),
      (err: CaptureError) => console.error(JSON.stringify(err))
    );
}

captureMedia('image'); // CRASHES!!
captureMedia('audio'); // WORKS!
captureMedia('video'); // WORKS!
```

No output. No warnings. No console output. Just *kaput*!

I feel like I'm missing something here but I can't see what it is. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

So, I ended up attempting to run this on my device from Xcode and finally got a useful error message! It turns out, my `config.xml` was missing *one* property for privacy permissions.

This was the one that was missing:

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription">
    <string>Allow photo library access.</string>
</edit-config>
```

Remember, you'll also need descriptions for the following (which I had):

- `NSCameraUsageDescription`
- `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`
- `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`

Cheers!